# How do you dispay the current logged in user in JSP, Java servlets

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

Hi i would like to know how i can display the current users username/name on a webpage when they have logged on... i am storing their username like this

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("currentUser", username);
```

and wat to display their username on the jsp(web page) like this

```
<p> welcome <% request.getSession().getAttribute("currentUser"); %></p>
```

however it doesn't work... any tips? or a method that works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using an expression, instead of a scriptlet:

```
<%= request.getSession().getAttribute("currentUser"); %>
```

Your scriplet will execute, but nothing is output.  The result of an expression is automtically written to the output.

Comment: thank you when i did <%= request.getSession().getAttribute("currentUser") %> it worked :)