# Current logged user in JSP file (Spring Security)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-security

I have problem with current logged user.

I have JSP file like this:

```
<ul class="nav--actions">
        <sec:authorize access="!isAuthenticated()">
            <li><a href="/login" class="btn btn--small btn--without-border">Zaloguj</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="btn btn--small btn--highlighted">Załóż konto</a></li>
        </sec:authorize>
        <sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
            ${userDetails}
            <form action="<c:url value="/logout"/>" method="post">
                <input class="btn btn--small btn--highlighted" type="submit" value="Wyloguj">
                <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
            </form>
        </sec:authorize>
    </ul>
```

And controller like this:

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @ModelAttribute("userDetails")
    public String userDetails(@AuthenticationPrincipal CurrentUser currentUser) {
        return currentUser.getUser().getEmail();
    }
}
```

(My username = email). How can I send this ModelAttribute ("userDetails") to my jsp file?

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692480/how-do-you-dispay-the-current-logged-in-user-in-jsp-java-servlets?